# Using same id for multiple buttons

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

Well, I'll say it like this.

I have a table with 2 columns. The first colum has names of items, the 2nd colums contains x amount of logos/indicators (ImageButtons). Several items can have the same **logo/indicators**.

My question is can I assign several ImageButtons to the same id? I've tried with using `android:id="@+id/logo1"` on the first and then `"android:id=@id/logo1"` on all the following occurences. This does not seem to work however. I can probably assign each button a different id and then just assign those to the same View, but it would be so much easier if I could just repeat the same ImageButton id for all the similar logos/indicators.

Comment: please define "not seem to work" and show some of your code/xml

Comment: Why should it work. Without looking into the code of findViewById I would guess that it stops after the I'd is found. And it would have to return an array of views as result.

Comment: About the "Does not seem to work" I mean that the clicks aren't registered. So any reused ids are just bypassed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, you can't use** the same ids in same layout if there behavior is different.

**Yes, you can use** the same ids but in different layouts. In fact, it may be good practice to.

Android has some default id [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529970/1012284)
they are declaring in ids.xml and reusing it in different views.