# Difference between @id and @android:id in android

Tags: android, widget

What is the difference between:

> android:id="@android:id/id_name1"

and

> android:id="@+id/id_name2"

Comment: Ok Sir i getting the idea about it... Thanking you!!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9529871/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sample references an id defined in the Android SDK itself.
The second sample creates a new id in your application's namespace.